# How to perform Ajax Call using backbone js in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
App.Views.AddPerson = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#addPerson',

        events: {
            'submit': 'submit',
        },

        submit: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newPersonName = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
            var person = new App.Models.Person({ name: newPersonName, age: newAge, occupation: newOccupation });
            this.collection.add(person);
            this.$('#todo-title').val('');

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '@Url.Action("InsertRecord", "Home")',
              data: newPersonName ,
              success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
              },
              error: function(){
                alert("error");
              }
            });
        }
    });
```

In the controller I have following method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertRecord(string str)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

**But it is not perform the ajax call and raise the error**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 submit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newPersonName = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
        var person = new App.Models.Person({ name: newPersonName, age: newAge, occupation: newOccupation });
        this.collection.add(person);
        this.$('#todo-title').val('');

       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: window.location + "Home/InsertRecord",
        data: {ID : newPersonName},
        success: function(data) {
        // Code after success },
          error: function(){
          alert("error");
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("InsertRecord", "Home")',
            data: {str:newPersonName} ,  // use the same paramtre name as in Controller
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
              },
              error: function(){
              alert("error");
              }
           });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually i tried the method you have written before posting the question..anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location + "Home/InsertRecord",
            data: {ID : newPersonName,
                  Name:newAge,
                  DeptID:newOccupation },
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
              },
              error: function(){
              alert("error");
              }
           });
```

Comment: Is it the answer to your own question ? You should provide more info about what your problem was and how this code solves it.

Comment: @jbl In my question I am performing a ajax call but that was not working. The main reason of the problem is the "@Url.Action".
I think the "@Url.Action" is not worked when we write code in .js file.

Comment: @BhupendraShukla '@Url.Action("actionname")' workes inside single quotes.Your problem was you didn't pass parametre name in data, I have answered your question by passing parametre name.